# Select first and last name using regex and notepad++ on a csv file

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I have a list of our clients in an CSV file.

Each line have the phone number, full name, e-mail and birth date. All separated by semicolon. Each line looks like this:

```
000000000;Client Full Name;client@email.com;1983-12-27;
```

I want to use notepad++ and regex to change all the names from full name to just the first and the last.

The final result should be something like this for all clients:

```
000000000;Client Name;client@email.com;1983-12-27;
```

Can anyone help me with the regex code please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
(;\w+)\s+\w+(\s+\w+;)
```

And replace with the following:

```
\1\2
```